# How to make my query selection faster over a 2 million records

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hql, mysql-workbench

Here i need a solution for my problem. I have a table that contain 2 million records related with geo coordinates. To get a perticular row from the table, query execution time will be  24 seconds. Here i want a selection of above 500 records for my application aspects. So any one kindly suggest any solutio n for making my query faster.

*Query*

```
SELECT * FROM myProject.MAP where start_ip<=419297593 and end_ip>=419297593;
```

*Table structur*

```
Field,Type,Null,Key,Default,Extra
start_ip,"int(10) unsigned",YES,MUL,NULL,
end_ip,"int(10) unsigned",YES,MUL,NULL,
country_id,int(11),NO,,NULL,
lat,double,YES,,NULL,
lng,double,YES,,NULL,
id,int(11),NO,PRI,NULL,auto_increment
```

Comment: show some of your queries, so that it will be easy for everyone to tune your queries

Comment: @PandiyanCool added the query

Comment: @AnkitBajpai i wanna select a perticular row among all. how can i limit my selection on 500.

Comment: Create indexes on `start_ip` and `end_ip`. This should speed things up.

Comment: Also post the table structure (ie, what are the data types and what indexes exist on the table)

Comment: @Ean indexing make query execution faster? plz be post an answer to this?

Comment: @Rachael am included the table structur what i have

Comment: Use the column names instead of *

Comment: why would this query produce 500 records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular query I would suggest a composite index like:

```
CREATE INDEX map_ix1 ON myproject.MAP (end_ip, start_ip);
```

If that is a unique combination, `create unique index ...`.

Also, don't use * in the query. If you need all columns it is still better (for maintainability) to explicitly declare the columns.  You may also consider a covering index (an index that contains all columns accessed in the query):

```
CREATE INDEX map_ix1 ON myproject.MAP (end_ip, start_ip, ...);
```

Comment: Is there any significat difference between composit index and other? I am tried what @Ean had post..But its still slow over a 20 values.

Comment: A composite index (where all the columns are used in the query) is almost always better than several single column indexes.

Comment: Thanks i will try with this too..To create a composit index can i remove already added index from that table. or it remove automatically

Comment: What columns do you use in the query? You might want to try an index like (end_ip, start_ip, <remaining columns>)

Comment: @Lennat am using start_ip and end_ip only

Comment: I mean in `SELECT ...`

Comment: lat,lng and country id only i need

Comment: Ok, you might want to include those at the end of the index. I also would recommend descending on start_ip, like: `CREATE INDEX map_ix1 ON myproject.MAP (end_ip, start_ip desc, lat, lng, county_id)` . It *should* perform much better that a single column index on start_ip

Comment: @Lennart: your index is simply waste of resources. Composite index is only applicable for fields which have constraints

Comment: @mvp, with constraint do you mean correlation?

Comment: @Lennart: constraint is something like `x=a` or `x>a` in `WHERE` clause. If you have `x=a AND y=b` you have two constraints. However, constraints like `x>a` are almost never truly indexable, and having just one such constraint makes all other non-exact constrains completely non-indexable

Comment: @mvp, I would refer to that as a predicate, but ok. Well, we both agree that an eq predicate is much better, but saying that an index like the one I suggested is a waste of resources seems a bit harsh. Or are you suggesting that a tablescan is as efficient as an indexscan over (start_ip) as an indexscan over (end_ip, start_ip) given the OP's query?

Comment: @Lennart: if you happen to know primary keys of 500 rows you are looking for, retrieving remaining fields from table takes milliseconds. But if you create fat combined index, server will have to keep it updated (not free), and index itself will take more space than it needs to be. So, this is waste, which OP comments about still bad performance confirm

Comment: @mvp, ok so the concern was the columns that makes the index covering. It certainly has less impact than the predicate columns, but can have a significant impact anyhow. The cost of maintaining the index is something that always has to be taken into account, here we know nothing about the read/write ratio. As for the bad performance I have not seen any feedback regarding the composite index yet.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create indexes on `start_ip` and `end_ip` columns. For the syntax and different types of indexes, have a look at [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

```
CREATE INDEX id_index ON myproject.MAP (start_ip);
```

As mentioned in the comments, the Visual Explain also helps you determine how to improve queries. You can compare two explains before and after adding indexes to see how they are different.

Comment: Use the Explain (and Visual Explain) feature in Workbench to help determine how to improve this query. As Ean suggests, add those indexes and you'll notice that the Explain plan changed. Research Explain and Indexes for additional information.

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com/ is a good free resource for learning about indexing and tuning.  It has examples for different databases as well.

Comment: For a single value query execution is fast...But selection over a 20 values is again take too much of time...Each query take transaction begin Time: 1403241044326 milleseconds  transaction end Time: 1403241077426 miliseconds. Total time take is:54315 m/s

Comment: @AravindCheekkallur What do you mean by selection over 20 values?

Comment: @Ean Here am converting ip in to a number then executing the query using the number. After indexing it looks faster for a single number. But i have more than 100 ips. Now the query is getting slow

Comment: I would suggest rewriting your query in a way that you can get all the results in one query (i.e. using `in`). Otherwise you are executing 100 separate queries (even though query itself is fast) and not much can be done to improve it.

Answer (score -1):

Your query seems wrong: why do you want to compare IP address as numeric value to anything? IP addresses are not something that you can meaningfully compare.

However, since you are using map data already (as you have lat, long, etc), that means you should be using spatial extensions. Good news is that spatial index allows you to execute queries of this exact kind very efficiently. You should already have created spatial index on `(lat, long)` or using `(lat, long)` as composite type `POINT` - this allows you to execute coordinate based search quickly.

If you still want to compare IP addresses, you can treat tuple `(start_ip, end_ip)` as spatial `POINT` and execute search for this point belonging to range you specify. This will give you maximum performance possible. You can read more about spatial extensions **[here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html)**.